# WPF Adorner Clipping

Tags: wpf, clipping, adorner

I have an `ItemsControl` in a `ScrollViewer`. The items in the `ItemsControl` are expanded to a `DataTemplate` which basically consists of an `Adorner`.

Now the problem is, when scrolling, the Visual Children of the `Adorner` are visible outside the `ScrollViewer`. Lets say I scroll from the Horizontal Offset 0 to 100, the Visual Children of the `Adorner` move to the left and are visible next to the `ScrollViewer`, although they should be hidden. Setting `ClipToBounds` on the `ItemsControl` or the `ScrollViewer` does not work.

I understand, that `Adorner` are rendered above all elements z-order wise, but they really shouldn't be visible in such cases as with the `ScrollViewer`. The adorned `Element` by the way behaves like expected and is not visible through the `ScrollViewer`.

Is there any easy way to "clip" the `Adorner`s, so that they are only visible in the visible scroll area?

Thanks,
Andrej

Comment: In the following thread Wei Zhou re-templates the ScrollViewer so the button's Adorner is constrained. [Implement selection highlighting - advice please](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/e060205e-5bfc-4f21-bf80-dfa55c44eb8a)

Comment: What version of .NET/WPF did this happen for you?  I'm actually trying to recreate this behavior and I can't.  Basically I want my error adorners to display past the bounds of the scrollviewer (without using a popup)

Answer (score 11):

Setting `ClipToBounds` on the containing control is not enough. You must set the adorner's `IsClipEnabled` property too.

Comment: This was best solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same problem when subclassing the WPFToolkit DataGrid to draw an adorner around the current cell.

The content of the ScrollViewer is rendered by a ScrollContentPresenter instance. ScrollContentPresenter has its own adorner layer, which is accessible through the ScrollContentPresenter.AdornerLayer property.

I found that my adorner correctly clips if I add it to that layer.

Comment: I use VisualTreeHelper to search the visual tree until I find a descendant of type ScrollContentPresenter. Take a look at the method in this thread - http://wpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=34542 .

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to push a clip region onto the drawing context, render whatever I needed, and pop the clipping at the end, like this:

```cs
drawingContext.PushClip(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, this.AdornedElement.RenderSize.Width, this.AdornedElement.RenderSize.Height)));
// continue drawing
drawingContext.Pop();
```

You can plug this in into any Adorner, the bounds are already available as part of the element.

Comment: If you're rending into a text box or something with a scroll viewer, you can use the ViewportWidth and ViewportHeight instead of RenderSize. You may need to add 4 to the ViewportWidth for text boxes though, because there's some weird padding