# Error Adorner in a Scrollviewer

Tags: wpf, adorner, adornerlayer, adornerdecorator

I'm trying to ensure that my error adorners don't get clipped by my scrollviewer's bounds. I have a series of textboxes that are at the edge of a fixed width scrollviewer (no horizontal scrolling, only vertical).  I then have adorners that flag textboxes with errors.

The problem is that the adorners get clipped at the edge of the scrollviewer.

Any ideas?

*Note:  I have tried wrapping everything in AdornerDecorator.

Comment: Note:  Here is a question that does the reverse of what I'm trying to do, but I can't recreate the problem he had ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372574

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so the solution to this problem is the same solution from the question I referenced in my comment above.

You need to [retemplate](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/e060205e-5bfc-4f21-bf80-dfa55c44eb8a) the ScrollViewer and add an AdornerDecorator to the template.

Something to note in general about Adorners ... if I have a problem with them, the solution tends to be wrapping the element in an AdornerDecorator, it's not always going to be the solution, it's worth a first look as it might be.

Comment: Where did you place the AdornerDecorator? I have tried it in every location I can think of and I am still having the same problem you had. I'm using .NET 3.5